# Unexpected behaviour running remote script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, centos6

I'm attempting to write a script that runs on a remote machine.

As this script is complex, I've broken parts of it down into functions that I then copy into the script using `typeset`.

When I run the script, I get the following error:

`bash: -c: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

However, there is no unexpected end of file! I ensured all `if`s had `fi`s, all `{` had `}`, etc.

I've ensured all indentation uses tabs (and spaces), and ensured new-line characters are consistent.

I've stripped the code down to a minimal example. It seems as though for a function to be valid, it needs to end in a construct such as `if` `fi` or `while` `done`.

Here's what isn't working.

```
func() {
  ls ~/
}

ssh -A -T user@machine_ip '
'$(typeset -f func)'
func
'
```

Line 4 coincides with the end `}` of the `func` function (counting lines from after `ssh -A -T...` as this error is happening on the remote machine).

Yet, if we add a construct to the end of the function, the home directory is printed as expected.

```
func() {
    ls ~/
    if [[ 1 ]]; then
      echo "Hello"
    fi
}
```

or

```
func() {
    ls ~/
    while false; do
        echo "Here"
    done
}
```

Output of `typeset -f func` is

```
func () 
{ 
    ls --color=auto ~/;
    if [[ -n 1 ]]; then
        echo "Hello";
    fi
}
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, remote machine is running Centos 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because bash plays with whitespace if you let it. Let me explain:

`$(typeset -f func)` will evaluate `typeset -f func` and insert its output into the current command line. If not quoted, it will also segment into parameters, which will have as a side effect collapsing of all whitespace to a single space. Thus, if `typeset -f func` prints (as it does on my system)

```
func () 
{ 
    /bin/ls --color=auto ~/
}
```

what you get with `$(typeset -f func)` is

```
func () { /bin/ls --color=auto ~/ }
```

(Try `echo $(typeset -f func)` if you don't believe me :D )

Now, bash is really bashful about accepting smushed-up code. For example, you may know that this is not grammatical:

```
if true then echo "yes" fi
```

and this is:

```
if true; then echo "yes"; fi
```

In the same way, the function definition's closing parenthesis is picky. Thus, this works:

```
func () { /bin/ls --color=auto ~/; }
```

but this doesn't:

```
func () { /bin/ls --color=auto ~/ }
```

For some reason, bash is fine with a keyword being just before the parenthesis:

```
func () { /bin/ls --color=auto ~/; if [[ -n 1 ]]; then echo "Hello"; fi }
func () { /bin/ls --color=auto ~/; while false; do echo "Here"; done }
```

---

To combat this... try not sending stuff from command line, which mangles your whitespace, but from redirection:

```
ssh -A -T user@machine_ip < <(typeset -f func; echo func)
```

Or, simplest of all, prevent `bash` mangling of whitespace using double quotes:

```
ssh -A -T user@machine_ip "$(typeset -f func)
func"
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, the way you use quotes make no sense to me.

```
ssh -A -T user@machine_ip '
'$(typeset -f func)'
func
'
```

the 2 first ' just echo an empty line. ( the 2nd ' close the 1st. logic ? )

Anyway.

```
$(typeset -f func)
func
```

the code above will execute func 2 times. 
At least, thats how it works for me

....